# Email is not working in Live only in Node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm using the node to send the email and it works fine in Local but when I upload on AWS instance it's not working.

To send the Email I'm using the Node Mailer which is very common so I'm not putting the whole code but I'm sharing the [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp) and the code is 100% the same.

I'm getting below Error in live only.

Note: I Enable the Google less secure app also.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: May [this](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution that It was related to AWS server config issue.

In AWS, EC2 -> Security Group I open all TCP port and tried and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

seems like they ask you to follow link in smtp server negotiations response, and probably fill captcha.

I'm not sure for less secure app, but for me creating application password for access email on this page

https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

worked properly both with nodemailer and Claws email client

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Enable less secure apps - https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
2. Disable Captcha temporarily so you can connect the new device/server - https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha